# Taxonomy category not working

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, ubercart

I'm creating a website which has 2 type of **categories**. One for the **Catalog (product type)** which works well and I created a **Company taxonomy catalog** too. If I create a product I can select the **Product type** and **the Company**. So I created a navigation for the **catalog** and for the **company**. If I click on the catalog product type it works great it shows the products which I added inside that catalog but if I click on the company it says that the taxonomy is empty and the product is not showing there. What can be set up bad here ? Im totally confused. (I'm creating Filters with Views).

Anybody got tips for this small error ? Thank you